# Why GLAutoDrawable doesn't have the method addMouseListener

Tags: java, jogl

I want to add a MouseListener from com.jogamp.newt.event.MouseListener
to an GLAutoDrawable like this:

```
/* inside the class that implements GLEventListener */   
@Override
     public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
       keyMaster = new KeyMaster();
       drawable.addMouseListener(keyMaster);
     }
```

GLAutoDrawable is from package javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable.
Eclipse says, that there is no addMouseListener methode.

But on http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/spec/prd/jsr-231-prd-javadoc/index.html
they say, it inherits the interface ComponentEvents, which does have this methode.

I also found on http://download.java.net/media/jogl/jogl-2.x-docs/index.html?javax/media/opengl/GLAutoDrawable.html, that there is no ComponentEvents interface as superclass.

How could that be. I found many examples that use drawable.addMouseListener(...)

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can clarify you.
GLDrawable is an interface implemented by GLCanvas.
GLDrawable can have a GLEventListener attached to it (so GLCanvas implements 'addGLEventListener' method).

GLCanvas is a subclass of awt.canvas -> awt.component so you can register mouse listeners to it.

GL events are register on the GLDrawable.
Mouse, keuboard, etc events are registered on the Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

As neil said, GLAutoDrawable is an interface. The actual class you get is probably either GLCanvas or GLJPanel, both of which can have mouse listeners attached to them.

However **you shouldn't be adding mouse listeners in init()**. init() is not only called when the component is first created - it can be called whenever the system needs to reinitialize GL, and that can be several times over the life of a component. Add any listeners when you create the GLCanvas or GLJPanel (yes, your app is creating them).